# Databricks and academic graph access

Tags: azure, apache-spark-sql, microsoft-graph-api, databricks, azure-databricks

I am using databricks to extract data from microsoft academic graph. When I ran the query

## Get affiliations

"Affiliations = MAG.getDataframe('Affiliations')
Affiliations = Affiliations.select(Affiliations.AffiliationId, Affiliations.DisplayName)
Affiliations.show(3)" given in their documentation I receive an error 
"shaded.databricks.org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.AzureException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid characters in hostname".
How do I resolve this issue?

Comment: What is the hostname the error message talks about?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have followed this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/academic-services/graph/tutorial-azure-databricks-hindex) without missing any steps.

By following this tutorial, I'm able to get  Affiliations as follows.

[image]

Hope this helps. Do let us know if you any further queries.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I found the mistake in the key for my storage account name. There was a space at the end of the valued of the key